# Using vim as the editor for the It's All Text! Firefox Add-on

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, vim

I am trying to use vim as the external editor for It's All Text! within Firefox. This works fine for standard http:// web pages, but when I try to use it within TiddlyWiki, 89 instances of vim are opened. I am guessing that the difference is that the TiddlyWiki page is a file on my local file system. I also created a simple html file and had the same problem. Is there a way around this problem?

From the comments:

> I am on Windows Vista if that makes a difference.

Comment: I am on Windows Vista, if that makes a difference.

Comment: hmm, difficult, interesting question. I'll fave it and follow progress if you don't mind

Comment: Also fave'd, I had the same thing happen to me on XP, but not every time. I had to kill all vim processes and restart Firefox to get my system back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [vimperator plugin](http://www.vimperator.org/vimperator) for firefox. Hitting CTRL+i within a textarea form will vim start as external process. This works almost everywhere - at least where I tried.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but that does work for me and I have already been using and loving vimperator, so it accomplishes the goal of using vim as the external editor for a local html file. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It was a bug in previous versions of It's All Text!.  Get the newest version; if there is still a bug, please report it via http://trac.gerf.org/itsalltext

Thanks!

FYI: I'm the author of "It's All Text!".

Answer (score 1):

Try [pentadactyl](http://dactyl.sourceforge.net/pentadactyl/) instead of vimperator. Millions of light-years better.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in It's All Text

Answer (score 0):

As of Firefox version 56+ many of the current extensions out there stopped working.

Another SU question pointed me towards [wasavi](https://github.com/akahuku/wasavi).

Although no longer listed on the Firefox addons store it can still be installed manually:

- Download the latest version via the "Latest and unstable version of wasavi for Firefox" link under the [How to install section in the Wasavi README](https://github.com/akahuku/wasavi#how-to-install)
- Unzip the downloaded file, you should find a `wasavi.xpi` file
- Navigate to the Firefox addons page (about:addons)
- Drag `wasavi.xpi` into the Firefox addons page
- Click the "Add" button in the prompt that appears

You can now use vim navigation keys in any text box by focusing the text box and hitting Ctrl + Enter.