# Modern Firefox Extension Which Allows Text Editing With Vim Keybinds?

Tags: firefox, vim, firefox-extensions

I would like to be able to edit text fields in Firefox with the vim keybinds.

I searched for addons in [previous](https://superuser.com/questions/527895/edit-text-areas-using-vi-key-bindings-inside-the-textbox-in-firefox-without-o) [answers](https://superuser.com/questions/73270/using-vim-as-the-editor-for-the-its-all-text-firefox-add-on?rq=1) but all the provided solutions did not work with the most recent version of firefox.

A popular recommendation was an extension named [wasavi](https://github.com/akahuku/wasavi). I ran into issues using this addon due to all the links to this addon being broken.

Another recommendation was [Vimperator](http://vimperator.org/vimperator). However a note on the website indicates that newer versions of firefox are no longer compatible with this version.

Similar issues were encountered with [EmbeddedEditor](https://people.ksp.sk/~martin/firefox/extensions/EmbeddedEditor/).

Another popular recommendation was [pterosaur](https://github.com/ardagnir/pterosaur), unfortunately the author of this extension had to stop maintaining it for work reasons.

pentadactyl was also recommended, however [the link provided](http://dactyl.sourceforge.net/pentadactyl/) was dead.

Comment: I mainly would like to edit "normal" (non about:*) web pages which have finished loading.

Comment: This is off topic for superuser.com anyway.

Comment: @EBGreen May I ask why? This is a direct follow up to 2 previous questions (linked) on super user. 1 of these questions was migrated from stackoverflow to super user.

Comment: @NoahHuppert Note that the previous question avoid saying "what tools do this for me?" and instead focus on "I have tried these things, how do I achieve this?" Tell us what tool *almost* got you to a solution. Tell us what happened and what final bits might be missing. Show your process. Just asking for product recommendations is off-topic here.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks for the response! In the processing of editing my question I actually stumbled upon a solution! It turns out the wasavi addon was de-listed from the addon store but can still be installed manually. Should I post my answer to another question? Or edit my answer in to this question (As this one is on hold).

Comment: I would probably say to post your findings in an answer to one of the other questions that you found, explaining that older solutions stopped working but here are current alternatives.

Comment: @Mokubai alright cool, should I delete this question or is the best course of action for it to be closed?

Comment: Its not a big difference at this point. If anything I'd be tempted to realise this as a duplicate of whichever you post to. That way we get an extra pointer towards the answer and other posts.

Comment: @Mokubai was going to post to #527895 b/c it originally mentioned wasavi (the tool I found a workaround for), but it looks like it got put on hold. Maybe I can manage to post an answer to 73270 before it gets put on hold to.

Comment: To answer your question: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research. Here are a few suggestions on how to properly ask this type of question.